# jQuery Form Plugin Not Submitting Data in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, internet-explorer-10, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a form that is submitting just fine in every browser except IE10. I am using the jQuery forms plugin and returning html. The form does submit, but the info in the data attribute is not being submitted. The script looks like this:

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{$data.paths.base_url}dashboard/ajax_edit_comment/" + id,
                    data: { comment: commentForm.find('.write-comment-comment').text(), name: curName },
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        commentForm.find('.write-submit').hide();
                        commentForm.find('.cancel-edit').hide();
                        commentForm.append('<img class="comment-loader" src="{$data.paths.base_url}public/frontend/images/stt/layout/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        //var commentData = data[0];
                        //var commentId = commentData.comment.id;

                        $(commentForm).parent().html(data);
                    }
                });
```

The variables in the script are defined before this and have already been checked to contain the correct values, for some reason the values are just not being submitted with the form.

UPDATE: I've come to realize that the problem is that despite me setting the type to post, it is actually submitting via get.

Comment: What's the version of JQuery you're using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.3